# Imacros script stops if HTTP answer code != 200

Tags: macros, vbscript, imacros

I have an iMacros macro, which actually works like expected:

```
 VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
 TAB T=1
 URL GOTO=https://example.com/?page={{!LOOP}}
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:
 ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Excel
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>Page<SP>>
```

But if any page gives any other HTTP status code as 200, my macro stops and then want to begin from the first page.

The question is: how can i achieve, that the macro doesn't stop, but just omit the page, which isn't available, in the best case after 5 access tryings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```

This will keep the macro running and skip to the next page.